# Issue with multiped conditions on groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large sales csv file that I want to analyze with specific questions.

[image]

**Now, I have a question that I want to analyze - What is the best time to advertise the products in San Francisco?**

I try to create a separate table with .loc the information of city and hours but it gave me an empty list:

```
San_Francisco_Hours_Results = new_all_data.loc[(new_all_data['City'] == 'San Francisco') & (new_all_data['Hours'])]
```

Also, I try to do straight conditions within the .groupby and I got entangled with this code.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you want to apply a condition to `Hours` or just include it in the output?

Comment: I think you can get your required subset using: `print(new_all_data[new_all_data['City'] == 'San Francisco (CA)'])`

Comment: @Muhammad there's probably a space before (CA)

Comment: @StuartMills, I want to include the Hours in the output, my end goal is to plot it and on the xlabel will be the Hours, ylabel will be the number of orders. All of that will be on only San Francisco.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan, I try the code that you wrote and it still gives me an empty list. To be honest I am trying to solve it by trying to use group by conditions (but I am not sure that it is possible)

Comment: @OrZemerTov can you provide copiable data? Also when you say "trying to use group by conditions" it is hard to help when we cannot see what you have tried.

Comment: @StuartMills, sorry I forgot to upload the code here, ```San_Francisco_Hours_Results = new_all_data.groupby(['City' == 'San Francisco (CA)','Hours'], as_index=False).sum()```

I get a error message of 'False'.